# How to provide correct css file link for svg file. angular 10

Tags: html, css, angular

Angular 10 CLI

the component has in the html object in which I refer to the svg file. In svg file, I can't correctly link to css file

html:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="../../assets/svg/favorite_full.svg"></object>
```

svg file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="????" ?>
<svg class="test" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
<path d="M16.5 3c-1.74 0-3.41.81-4.5 2.09C10.91 3.81 9.24 3 7.5 3 4.42 3 2 5.42 2 8.5c0 3.78 3.4 6.86 
8.55 11.54L12 21.35l1.45-1.32C18.6 15.36 22 12.28 22 8.5 22 5.42 19.58 3 16.5 3zm-4.4 
15.55l-.1.1-.1-.1C7.14 14.24 4 11.39 4 8.5 4 6.5 5.5 5 7.5 5c1.54 0 3.04.99 3.57 2.36h1.87C13.46 5.99 
14.96 5 16.5 5c2 0 3.5 1.5 3.5 3.5 0 2.89-3.14 5.74-7.9 10.05z"/>
</svg>
```

my svg file is in src / assets / svg / favorite_border.svg

I want to link to any css file (no matter what in this case, I don't understand how it works) For example, app.component.scss

my project structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHqBd.png)

I will be glad for any help / hint

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the file with FileReader(), then you can link with ngClass or ngStyle.